# How refund is possible for event participants in civicrm?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civicontribute, evaluating-civicrm

I am using civicrm 4.6 in wordpress where users register for the events. We also want to allow users cancel their registrations and admin can refund them. We are using Stripe payment processor and participants make payment through credit card. Is their any in built feature to refund event participants? or how to integrate that?

Answer (score 2):

It's been my experience that refunds need to be done with the payment processor, not inside CiviCRM. We use Authorize.net and we just log into the system and do the refund from there. Payment systems can be real finicky when it comes to refunds because of fraud.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do a batch refund in Authorize.net?

Comment: I don't know, as I don't handle that side of things.